# Query on LocalDateTime

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, datetime, jodatime

I have a table containing records with DateTime datatype in MySQL (e.g. 2013-01-17 21:16:06),
while on my entity I choose LocalDateTime datatype for the date field. During my queries I would like to retrieve all records based on 2 Dates only (fromDate and toDate using a datepicker). Lets say I choose the same date for both fromDate and toDate, the issue is both value would be the same since the time is 00:00:00, hence gives no result from the database.

I am curious if I have used the right datatype from Joda. Am I required to adjust the time for both values lets say 00:00:00 for fromDate and 23:59:59 for toDate ? Or what's the better approach ?

Comment: Select where date >= fromDate 00:00 and date < toDate + 1 day 00:00. This will make your query independent of the resolution of date column.

Comment: which means I am required to construct a new LocalDateTime that is exactly one day after the toDate. Is that it ?

Comment: Yes. OR better, you can tell MySQL to add one day to the specified date (using DATE_ADD function or just `/*SELECT*/ '2013-01-17' + INTERVAL 1 DAY`).

Comment: Got it working. E.g. 2013-01-17T00:00:00.000 - 2013-01-18T00:00:00.000. Does this mean the toDate record was inserted on the same date as fromDate ? Or the record belongs to the next day ? You could post your comment as answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a datetime column and two arbitrary dates as input, you can write:

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE `datetime` >= @startDate
AND   `dateTime` <  @endDate + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Where:

- startDate is the starting date, inclusive
- endDate is the ending date, exclusive

What the above means is best explained through the following cases:

1. To see all records for `2013-01-17` (one day) startDate should be `2013-01-17` and endDate should be `2013-01-17`
2. To see all records for `2013-01-17` - `2013-01-18` (two days) startDate should be `2013-01-17` and endDate should be `2013-01-18`.

This makes choosing the dates intuitive. The `<` sign ensures that the calculated end date is excluded from the results (e.g. in the first case the query omits `2013-01-18 00:00:00 records).